# Scaling of basis hat functions to given domain

Tags: analysis, change-of-basis

I would like to transform the standard function values of the hat functions from $[0,1]$ to a given domain $[-R,R]$, whereas the standard hat functions are given through:

$\begin{align}
\varphi(x) = \max\{1-|x|,0\}
\end{align}
$

I am not able to find that out. I also made a small illustration:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct that

$\begin{align}
\psi(x) = \varphi\left( \frac{x - R}{2R}\right)
\end{align}$

seems like the solution.